# Visual Studio Unit Testing Assert.AreEqual Fails with Identical Expected and Actual Values

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am a total newb when it comes to Unit Testing, so please pardon me if this is total ignorance.  But I can't get this method to pass a unit test even if I provide the exact same values for the expected and actual.  When I set breakpoints and step through, I have confirmed that both expected and actual variables are a string array containing two items, blah and blah.  But the test still fails every time stating that "Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected: System.String[] Actual:System.String[]"

```
namespace TestProject1

{
 public class Testing
 {
    public string[] PMDate(string lastPm)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastPm))
            return new []{"blah", "blah"};
        string[] results = lastPm.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);

        if (results.Length < 2)
            return new[] {"blah", "blah"};

        return results;
    }
 }
[TestClass()]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void PmDateTest()
    {
        Testing test = new Testing();
        string[] expected = test.PMDate("01/01/1900");
        string[] actual = test.PMDate("01/01/1900");
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your test will be using `object.Equals`, which isn't overridden for arrays. In other words, this will print false:

```
var x = new[] { 0 };
var y = new[] { 0 };
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));
```

You should use [`CollectionAssert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx) instead for collections:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Comment: CollectionAssert doesn't seem to be widely advertised in unit testing tutorials and such...very useful for sure

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because the string arrays are two different objects, even if they contain the same values, they are different objects. You can simply verify this by checking expected.GetHashcode() and actual.GetHashCode() at runtime and you will see that the hash codes are different